# A contradiction in the derivation of electrostatic potential energy?

Tags: electrostatics, work, potential-energy, conventions, integration

I am a 12th grade high school student with no knowledge of vector calculus and more advanced physics.. so if possible, please try to refrain from using advanced concepts which I do not understand.

While trying to derive the formula for electrostatic potential energy for myself, I tried two different approaches
In both the cases my reference point was $\infty$, so $U_\infty = 0$

The situation is as follows, there are two point charges: a fixed source charge $Q$ and a test charge $q_0$.

In **Case 1:**

$Q$ and $q_0$ are initially separated by a distance $r$ and $Q$ applies a force of $\frac{KQq_0}{x^2}$ where $x$ is the separation between the charges at any instant, initially $r$
So the work done by the source charge is given by,
$$W = \int_r^{\infty}\frac{KQq_0}{x^2}dx \\
=> W = \left.\frac{-KQq_0}{x}\right\rvert_r^\infty \\
=> W = \frac{-KQq_0}{\infty} + \frac{KQq_0}{r} = \frac{KQq_0}{r}
$$
Thus we get $\Delta U = U_\infty - U_r = -W => -U_r = - \frac{KQq_0}{r}$ or,
$$U_r = \frac{KQq_0}{r}$$
which is consistent with the regular result.

Now the problem arises with case 2

**Case 2:**

$Q$ and $q_0$ are initially separated by a distance $\infty$ and an external force (always equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to Electrostatic force) brings the test charge towards the source charge upto a separation of $r$, here the electrostatic force and displacement of the test charge are in opposite directions. Thus work done by source charge is given as,
$$ W = \int_\infty^r(-1)\frac{KQq_0}{x^2}dx$$[-1 being multiplied to account for the fact that force and displacement are antiparallel]

$$=> W = \left.\frac{KQq_0}{x}\right\rvert_\infty^r \\
=> W = \frac{KQq_0}{r} - \frac{KQq_0}{\infty} = \frac{KQq_0}{r}$$

So now we get $\Delta U = U_r - U_\infty = -W => U_r = - \frac{KQq_0}{r}$
$$U_r = -\frac{KQq_0}{r}$$

Clearly, even though I took the same reference point, I got different results, and since electrostatic force is conservative, shouldn't the change in potential energy be only dependent on final and initial positions?

I do not understand if I made an error in calculation or if I haven't understood the concept clearly.

After doing all this, I got confused regarding the work done by an external agent. Because in the second case if we were to evaluate the work done by the external agent we would get $-\frac{KQq_0}{r}$ but, should it not be positive? As the external agent is overcoming the electrostatic repulsion. I know that my result in case 2 must be wrong because 2 contradictions are arising, but I cannot figure out where I went wrong.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

EDIT 1: To clear any confusion, I am attaching a diagram for both cases.

[image: diagram]

Comment: Could you explain what you are physically trying to achieve in both scenarios? as per the rule in my answer, what you are doing is mathematically right, and I think the issue is in your setup. I see that in 2, you are trying to bring the charge in to r, but in scenario 1, it's not clear to me what you are trying to do. I think one of the signs of your charges needs to change since I think in one case you have an attractive force and one you have a repulsive, but I'm not sure if I'm getting what you are trying to do right.

Comment: @Relativisticcucumber I added a diagram to better explain what is going on, i understand that the expression for work done that I got is mathematically consistent, and that is my problem because shouldn’t it be negative of each other as I’m swapping the final and initial points? Also please check the diagram, if it’s not clear, I will try to explain again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend contextualizing work in terms of *energy transfer* and forces as *means by which energy is transferred*. Identify what mathematical object with energy the energy is coming from, and what mathematical object the energy is going to, and what force is facilitating the transfer. Note that negative work (negative energy transfer) is just transfer in the opposite direction: "A does 5J of work on B" and "B does -5J of work on A" are the same sentence.

In scenario 1, you're calculating the energy transferred from the electric field's potential energy to the particle's kinetic energy.

In scenario 2 you've set up an extra force such that net force is zero. Energy transferred to or from kinetic energy is therefore also zero. As written, we're calculating the energy transferred from the potential energy of the fuel of the tiny rocket that's providing the force that's pushing the particle, to the electric field's potential energy. At the end, when you express $U$, you're expressing the potential energy of the thing the energy is going out of, so of course $U(r)$ is negative: the rocket has that much less fuel than it started with.

Typically we would not be creating tiny rockets to push around our charged particles and measuring the work done by means of the rocket's pushing force on the electric field. We would again want to express the energy transferred from the electric field's potential energy to the kinetic energy of the charged particle, which started with some sufficiently high kinetic energy to traverse the distance.

In that case, since we're going from bigger x to smaller x, $dx$ is already negative, and there's no need to add an extra minus sign (which will give us a sign error). If the charges are opposite signed, we'll find that the work was positive, the kinetic energy is bigger, and the potential energy is smaller. If the charges are the same sign, we'll find that the work was negative, the kinetic energy is smaller, and the potential energy is bigger. "Potential energy does X work on particle kinetic energy" and "particle kinetic energy does -X work on potential energy" are the same sentence.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense to me, thank you for the explanation, I think my problem is cleared up. Thanks a lot!